# Re-install Buildkit on Ubuntu for Windows

Tags: civicrm-buildkit, windows

I have just installed BuildKit on Ubuntu for Windows as root by mistake. Is there a way I can uninstall and start again? Can I just delete the buildkit folder?

Also, I don't need to install Apache, PHP and MySQL, as these are already installed. Is there a particular command for installing the build kit without these? I was following the instructions at https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/tools/buildkit/.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you've run `amp`, you should also delete the hidden folder `$HOME/.amp`.  Leaving `--full` out of the install command will skip installing apps.  Hoewver, There is no side effect to reinstalling the apps, and it includes ancillary programs like `zip` and `curl`, so you're most likely best off running with `--full`.  It will also restart Apache for you, which might be necessary.

Comment: Thanks Jon G for your help. Just to confirm - I just need to delete the Buildkit folder and then reinstall?

Comment: Yes, assuming that you haven't tried to run `amp` yet.